# How do you compile against a jar file in Java 9?

Tags: java, classpath, java-9, junit5

Java 9 introduced the concept of modules, which do not explicitly replace jar files, but the old `--classpath` option seems to be gone.

<strike>The command `javac --help` no longer mentions the classpath.</strike>

I am trying to compile some student work against JUnit:

```
> javac *.java --classpath junit.jar
```

But I get a variety of errors, depending on what I try. For the example above:

```
javac: invalid flag: --classpath
```

My Java version is:

```
> java --version
java 9
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
```

I'm not trying to use a module, just a .jar file that I could include in IntelliJ by specifying a libs folder.

**Edit**:
My real problem was that I was not including the correct jars. Compiling against IntelliJ's default JUnit5 configuration worked:

```
 javac -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5\plugins\junit\lib\junit-jupiter-api-5.0.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5\plugins\junit\lib\opentest4j-1.0.0.jar" *.java
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misspelled the option.  According to the [javac options page for Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__BHCGAJDC):

> `--class-path` *path* , `-classpath` *path*, or `-cp` *path*
>
> Specifies where to find user class files and annotation processors. This class path overrides the user class path in the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

For some reason, if you use the two hyphens option `--`, there is a hyphen in "classpath": `--class-path`.  The one hyphen option `-` has no hyphen in "classpath": `-classpath`.

Any of these are valid:

```
javac *.java --class-path junit.jar

javac *.java -classpath junit.jar

javac *.java -cp junit.jar
```